# machine learning algorithms which can do both classification and regression

Tags: machine-learning

I know few algorithms can be used to solve both classification and regression problems Ex: Decision trees(CART), Neural networks.Can you let me know what are the other algorithms which can be used in similar way

Comment: Gaussian processes can also be used both for regression and classification. SVMs too by the way.

Answer (score 4):

There is a huge space of algorithms that would be applicable to this answer, many more than can be practically listed.

If you're using R, you can find a list of algorithms implemented in the `caret` package by:

```
modelLookup()
```

Which will return a list of implemented models, with the logical values:

```
forReg
forClass
```

Which will tell you which are suitable for both. As a one-liner,

```
unique(modelLookup()[(modelLookup()$forReg & modelLookup()$forClass),]$model)
```

Will provide a list of such models:

```
╔═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ "avNNet"              "bag"                 "bagEarth"            ║
║ "bagEarthGCV"         "bartMachine"         "bayesglm"            ║
║ "bdk"                 "blackboost"          "Boruta"              ║
║ "BstLm"               "bstSm"               "bstTree"             ║
║ "cforest"             "ctree"               "ctree2"              ║
║ "dnn"                 "earth"               "elm"                 ║
║ "evtree"              "extraTrees"          "gam"                 ║
║ "gamboost"            "gamLoess"            "gamSpline"           ║
║ "gaussprLinear"       "gaussprPoly"         "gaussprRadial"       ║
║ "gbm"                 "gcvEarth"            "glm"                 ║
║ "glmboost"            "glmnet"              "glmStepAIC"          ║
║ "kernelpls"           "kknn"                "knn"                 ║
║ "logicBag"            "logreg"              "mlp"                 ║
║ "mlpML"               "mlpWeightDecay"      "mlpWeightDecayML"    ║
║ "nnet"                "nodeHarvest"         "parRF"               ║
║ "partDSA"             "pcaNNet"             "pls"                 ║
║ "plsRglm"             "randomGLM"           "ranger"              ║
║ "rbf"                 "rbfDDA"              "rf"                  ║
║ "rfRules"             "rknn"                "rknnBel"             ║
║ "rpart"               "rpart1SE"            "rpart2"              ║
║ "RRF"                 "RRFglobal"           "simpls"              ║
║ "spls"                "svmBoundrangeString" "svmExpoString"       ║
║ "svmLinear"           "svmLinear2"          "svmPoly"             ║
║ "svmRadial"           "svmRadialCost"       "svmRadialSigma"      ║
║ "svmSpectrumString"   "treebag"             "widekernelpls"       ║
║ "xgbLinear"           "xgbTree"             "xyf"                 ║
╚═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Please note that this is not an exhaustive list of machine learning algorithms suitable for both regression and classification, but only of those implemented in the `caret` package in R.